# Renaming folders in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have a folder in Team Foundation Server with several sub-folders:

- candidates

  - beta1
  - beta2
  - rc1
  - ga

I'd like to move three of them under a new folder:

- candidates

  - defunct

    - beta1
    - beta2
    - rc1
  - ga

Each folder contains tens of thousands of files of various sizes. They are all branches of some other folder. I don't have them checked out in my working folder, but they are under a mapped folder.

The Rename option is greyed out in TFS. When I try to rename `beta1` to `defunct\beta1`, the TF command says:

> The item $/blah/candidates/beta1 could
>   not be found in your workspace.

I've tried getting a single file beneath beta1, but that doesn't fix it.

I've also tried specifying the full paths starting with `$`. And if I unmap this location from my workspace, it complains that it could not determine the workspace (even though I'm telling it two paths on the server.)

I get the crazy impression that I will have to physically download about 100,000 files, just so I can tell the server to rename some folders above them! This cannot possibly be true, in a sane world. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Who said the world was sane?  :D  Good question, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's not as bad as I thought!

If I say:

```
tf get beta1
```

and so on, for each of the sub-folders, it only gets the files immediately under that folder. This isn't anything like as bad. And then the Rename command appears enabled in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use a one-level workspace mapping.  Unlike the non-recursive "Get", this can be done entirely from the UI.

Further reading:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138514.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/03/04/tfs-workspaces-2005-and-orcas.aspx